# Swift: How to arrange UIViews inside UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Real simple (*and I've reviewed articles for 30 minutes with no match*), I have a **UIViewController** in a swift storyboard.

1. I needed to add a background image to the screen, so I added a **UIImageView**, set my background image, worked great.
2. I also added a **UIView** called `ButtonsView` "above" (*meaning below in the storyboard editor*) the **UIImageView** so that when I programmatically add images to the **UIViewController** so they appear over the background.
3. Now I need to my code that previously used the `addSubview` to the main `VC.view` to add to the newly created `VC.view.ButtonsView` in the storyboard.

I can't seem to get the compiler to see my **UIView** `ButtonsView` regardless of what identifier or accessibility I use in the editor. I also can't find any documentation on this specific process.

**How doe one programmatically reference a UIView inside a UIView inside a UIViewController?**

I'm 100% storyboard for all the above.

[image]

Comment: "above (meaning below..." what does this mean? Can you mockup a picture in Photoshop to explain what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "regardless of what identifier or accessibility I use in the editor", can you give a more specific example of what you are trying to do and how it is not working?

Comment: I added a photo to help. I'm assuming I can create a text identifier in the inspector to reference this UIView without creating an actual class for it. Is that right?

Comment: you can get reference of view by using tags, you can set tag to particular view in storyboard and you can get view from tag programatically

Comment: I saw the tag method by utterly loathe the idea of some arbitrary numbering system. Isn't there an alphanumeric reference method? Perhaps I just create a Class for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing an *outlet*. Give CategoryViewController an `@IBOutlet` property (let's call it `buttonView`) that is an Optional UIImageView, and hook it in the storyboard to the actual ButtonView.